# Enabling both Identity Authentication & JWT Authentication in .NET 6 Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am building .NET 6 application that includes Angular App as a dashboard. My application requires both default identity authentication (for routine login, and authorization purposes) and JWT Authentication to authorize the validity of API requests from the angular application.

I added both default identity authentication and JWT authentication code in my application program for that purpose.cs file is shown below.

Default Identity Code

```
builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Password settings
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;

    // Lockout settings
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    // User settings
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
       "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
});
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    //options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(150);
    // If the LoginPath isn't set, ASP.NET Core defaults 
    // the path to /Account/Login.
    options.LoginPath = "/signin";
    options.LogoutPath = "/signout";
    // If the AccessDeniedPath isn't set, ASP.NET Core defaults 
    // the path to /Account/AccessDenied.
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/accessdenied";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

JWT Authentication Settings

```
 builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
 {
     options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
 })
 .AddJwtBearer(options =>
 {
     options.SaveToken = true;
     options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
     options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
     {
         ValidateIssuer = true,
         ValidateAudience = true,
         ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["SiteSettings:URL"],
         ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["SiteSettings:URL"],
         IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_jwt_key))
     };
  });
```

Now the problem is if I leave both settings, only JWT authentication works and default identity authentication stopped working. If I remove JWT authentication, default identity authentication starts working.

I need both authenticating scheme within single application. Can anyone guide me for better approach.

Comment: have you considered [Rick Strahl's](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2022/Mar/29/Combining-Bearer-Token-and-Cookie-Auth-in-ASPNET) solution?

Comment: @pthomson That was a great article that almost got me there but I want to use the default Identity, not a manual cookie implementation, any idea?  I feel like it should be simple and I'm just missing the correct config